# Row added by directive via 'template' is being added to the top of the table?

Tags: angularjs, templates, directive

The code is being rendered like this :-

directive's template is at the top and then the thead is being rendered, but thead is expected to be at the top.

here is HTML

```
 <div class="panel_content">
    <table summary="A table listing various other formats for this product">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Other Formats</th>
          <th scope="col" class="site amount"><span>price</span></th>
          <th scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>New from</span></th>
          <th scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>Used from</span></th>
          <th scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span></span></th>
          <th scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span></span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <dir></dir>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

this is the directive

```
app.directive('dir', function() {
            return {
              restrict: 'E',
              replace: true,
              template: '<tr><td>asdf</td></tr>'
            };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`tbody` does not expect your directive `dir` tag (expects `tr`). Try to modify the code like:

```
app.directive('dir', function() {
            return {
              restrict: 'A',
              replace: true,
              template: '<tr><td>asdf</td></tr>'
            };
});
```

and use

```
<tbody>
    <tr dir></tr>
</tbody>
```